# ngCordova HealthKit plugin ARC warning and app crash

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, healthkit, ngcordova

I'm having trouble with a ngCordova plugin, [HealthKit](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/healthkit/) 0.3.3, when used with my Ionic Cordova app.

The app is just a skeleton, there's almost no code except to set up the app and to include $cordovaHealthKit in the contoller.

After building the app and loading it in Xcode, I see an ARC warning in XCode, pointing to the improper use of self in the plugin source code

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

The warning is: *ARC Retain Cycle: Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle*

I have the HealthKit entitlement enabled in XCode, but when I run the app in XCode it crashes.

```
0x196717bd0 <+16>:  ldp    x10, x11, [x9, #16] WebThread (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14b4fbeb8)
```

I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is an issue I should report at the HealthKit plugin Github page

Any thoughts gratefully received.

[image: HealthKit ARC Warning]

/plugins/com.telerik.plugins.healthkit/src/ios/com.telerik.plugins.healthkit/HealthKit.m
[image]